# Android and MySQL Server Communication

Tags: android, mysql, ajax, json, web-services

I am a newbie in Android programming and currently I would like to develop an Android application where it needs to be able to enter data like a picture and some other information into a database table.

I have read about json and also about Webservices but I am still kinda confused bout it. Which one to use or how to start it? I would be really glad any of you guys are able to give any idea or suggestions on any tutorials or journals in which i can use to have a headstart on this project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This kind of question is not a good fit for SO. Go do some research, try out some coding, then if you run into problems with your ***code***, come back and ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of jSON and your webservice to get MySQL communication done from your android application, I currently use a lot of this because I like to have my websites linked to the same database essentially.This is a guide for jSON, MySQL and php backend you might find useful, let me know if it was useful [MySQL Guide](http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/connecting-to-mysql-database-t50063.html)

Comment: Thanks man, the guide does give me a good idea on how to start. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, it is a very good example of connecting to remote database and json. Good luck